# Wagtail page context in Streamfield template

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have StructBlock with it's own template, within a StreamField. I'm trying to access the page object from said template.

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags article_tags %}

  {%  article_constants as constants %}
    <div id="interactions__combo__addition" class="col-md-6">
      <h3>
        {% include_block page.translated_title %}
        + 
        <span id="interactions-combo-addition-temp">?</span> =
      </h3>
      <div alt="dangerous to synergy bar" style="height:10px; width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="interactions__combo__result col-md-5">
      <h3 class="interactions__combo__result__title">
       {{ constants.select_element }}
      </h3>
      <p class="interactions__combo__result__description">
        {{ constants.none_selected_text }} 
        {% include_block page.colour %}.
      </p>
    </div>
```

`{% include_block page.colour %}` and `{% include_block page.translated_title %}` render nothing.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `{% include_block %}` tag when outputting the StreamField on your page template. For example, if your StreamField is called `body`, use `{% include_block page.body %}` on your page template. This will ensure that the context variables from the outer template (including `page`) are available in your StructBlock's template - if you use `{{ page.body }}` instead, the StructBlock template will render, but won't have access to the variables from the outer template.

Don't use `{% include_block %}` for fields of `page` that are not StreamFields, such as `page.translated_title`.